# date_create() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6

lo que quiero hacer es traer la fecha de una tabla y compararla con la actual pero me sale el error del titulo.

Son 2 tablas: users y histories

un usuario puede tener muchas historias

y una historia solo puede tener un usuario

Modelo History

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class History extends Model
{
    public function claimant(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function claimant_id(){
        $total = User::join('histories','users.id','=','histories.claimant_id')->select(DB::raw('users.date_membership_annual'));
        return $total;
    }

    public function diasMembership(){
        $fecha1 = date_create($this->claimant_id());
        $fecha2 = date_create("Y-m-d");
        $dias = date_diff($fecha1, $fecha2)->format('%m');
        return $dias;
    }
}
```

blade

```
<input type="text" value="{{ $history->diasMembership() }}">
```

Comment: Hay varios problemas ahí. Uno es que `$this->claimant_id()` te va a devolver un objeto query builder, y de ahí el error. ¿Que pasa si en la vista pones `{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($history->claimant->date_membership_annual)->diffInMonths(now()) }}`?

Comment: o que le podría hacer al modelo? no es necesario dejar el modelo así, si es necesario cambiarle el código no importa. Ahora que pueda ensayo lo de la vista y te comento

Comment: también he intentado usando el de claimant en lugar el de claimant_id y me suelta lo mismo solo que en lugar de $this->claimant_id ponia $this->claimant->date_membership_annual pero pues también debe estar mal

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ amigo ya ensaye y me aparece lo mismo :/

Comment: O sea... esta función `diasMembership()` que pusiste en el modelo, no va a funcionar, tiene un error en cada línea, por lo tanto, no la uses. Lo que te propuse es una alternativa a lo que creo que estás queriendo hacer, pero tampoco es claro lo que quieres hacer, así que si lo explicas, mejor.